# How would I recreate the list of pages grid that's seen in CMS->Pages in my own module in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

I have created a Magento admin module with it's own menu and page in the back-end, and am trying to recreate how `CMS->Pages` lists every page in it's grid on my own page, then add my own column.

So far, after switching on template hints for the admin section, I have seen that the original Magento CMS section template is loaded from `adminhtml\default\default\template\widget/grid.phtml`.

I have copied the contents of this file to my page, but of course, the `$this` reference that the original uses doesn't have the same loaded classes/data asociated with it on my own module page.

Can anyone tell me if I'm along the right lines with this, or how I might achieve the same effect as `CMS->Pages`, but on my own page and adding my own column?

Comment: Are you trying to create a grid with your custom module table info or are you trying to create a grid that display cms page related info?

Comment: @R.S CMS page related info. I'd essentially like just like a mirror of the existing but with one additional column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you can create a custom module that extend /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Block/Grid.php

Assuming that you're adding a database field to cms table

Create /app/code/local/RWS/CmsGrid/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
   <blocks>
      <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
          <cms_block_grid>RWS_CmsGrid_Block_Cms_Block_Grid</cms_block_grid>
        </rewrite>
      </adminhtml>
   </blocks>
</global>
```

Create /app/code/local/RWS/CmsGrid/Block/Cms/Block/Grid.php

```
class RWS_CmsGrid_Block_Cms_Block_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Grid
{

   protected function _prepareColumns()
   {

      $this->addColumn('xxxxxx', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Xxxxx'),
          'align'     => 'left',
          'index'     => 'title',
     ));
     ..........
```

See more info

- [Magento - overriding Adminhtml block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876897/magento-overriding-adminhtml-block)
- http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will this add a new field to the existing CMS->Pages or create a duplicate version of CMS->Pages on my own module page? as the latter is what I require, cheers.

Comment: Have further tested and it works really well, so thanks again.